# Marshal serializing a Hash with a block constructor

Tags: ruby, hashmap

Here's a piece of code

```
myHash = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = []}
myHash[5] << 1 # example operation
Marshal.dump(myHash)
```

I use this often when I try to operate it with arbitrary keys, and I didn't want to explicitly write something like this

```
myHash = Hash.new
myHash[5] ||= []  # initialize it first, if needed
myHash[5] << 1    # example operation
Marshal.dump(myHash)
```

While it is only a single line of code difference, to me using the block version looks somewhat cleaner.

However, issues occur during the serialization process

```
in `dump: can't dump hash with default proc (TypeError)
```

Is there a way to serialize this while continuing to use the block form of the constructor? Or do I have to stick with explicitly checking and initializing any values before I try to operate on my hash?

I would say no, because there is no real way for ruby to determine how the hash should automatically generate the value when a key is missing without the original proc that was passed in.

Comment: It is not really relevant to the problem but I've clarified what I mean

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360541/marshal-cant-dump-hash-with-default-proc-typeerror

Comment: That question asks why it happens, not how it could be addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the default behavior before dumping the hash.

```
myHash = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = []}
myHash[5] << 1
myHash.default = nil
Marshal.dump(myHash)
```

Or, since you seem to be interested in conserving vertical space:

```
myHash = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = []}
myHash[5] << 1
Marshal.dump(myHash.tap {|h| h.default = nil })
```

However, this permanently changes the hash so that it no longer has a default. If that bothers you, but temporarily duplicating the top level of your hash does not, throw in a `.dup`:

```
Marshal.dump(myHash.dup.tap {|h| h.default = nil })
```

and now the default behavior of the original hash remains unchanged.

Comment: Thanks, when the data is dumped out, the hash may still be used, so preserving the proc would be important there. When the data is loaded, it would be merged with a hash that has the proc.

Comment: As for vertical space, it's not so much that, but if I had to include an extra method call to check if a key is properly initialized before operating on it in every attempt to access the hash, that is unnecessary clutter.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Marshal.html 3rd paragraph:

Some objects cannot be dumped: if the objects to be dumped include bindings, procedure or method objects, instances of class IO, or singleton objects, a TypeError will be raised.

Here's a simple example:

```
class X
  def initialize a
    @a = a
  end
end
```

> Marshal.dump(X.new(1))

=> "\x04\bo:\x06X\x06:\a@ai\x06"

> proc = Proc.new { 1 }

=> Proc:0x007ff992716428

> Marshal.dump(X.new(proc))

TypeError: no _dump_data is defined for class Proc

When you create a hash with a block, the hash has a default_proc attribute that is a Proc:

> h = Hash.new { 1 }

=> {}

> h.default_proc

=> #Proc:0x007ff99506ce30@

When you create a hash without a block, it has no default_proc:

> h = Hash.new

=> {}

> h.default_proc

=> nil